# Столкнулся с проблемой при создании бота ChatGpt для telegram на Golang

Tags: telegram-bot, golang

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api"
    gogpt "github.com/sashabaranov/go-gpt3"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Config struct {
    TelegramToken string `mapstructure:"tgToken"`
    GptToken      string `mapstructure:"gptToken"`
}

type GptBotStruct struct {
    MaxTokensGpt int
    NameBot      string
}

func LoadConfig(path string) (c Config, err error) {
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
    viper.AddConfigPath(path)

    viper.AutomaticEnv()

    err = viper.ReadInConfig()

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = viper.Unmarshal(&c)
    return
}

func sendChatGPT(c *gogpt.Client, sendText string, gptM GptBotStruct) string {
    ctx := context.Background()

    req := gogpt.CompletionRequest{
        Model:            gptM.NameBot,
        MaxTokens:        gptM.MaxTokensGpt,
        Prompt:           sendText,
        FrequencyPenalty: 0,
        PresencePenalty:  0,
    }

    resp, err := c.CreateCompletion(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        return "ChatGPT API error"
    } else {
        return resp.Choices[0].Text
    }
}

func main() {
    // Reading config.yaml
    config, err := LoadConfig(".")

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("fatal error with config.yaml: %w", err))
    }

    // Chat GPT initialization
    chatGPT := gogpt.NewClient(config.GptToken)

    // Telegram initialization
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(config.TelegramToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true // set to false for suppress logs in stdout
    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    // Start Telegram long polling update
    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 5
    updates, _ := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

    GptMode := GptBotStruct{
        MaxTokensGpt: 3000,
        NameBot:      "text-davinci-003",
    }

    //Check message in updates
    for update := range updates {
        if update.Message == nil {
            continue
        }

        checkOne := strings.HasPrefix(update.Message.Text, "/text")
        checkTwo := strings.HasPrefix(update.Message.Text, "/code")
        checkThree := strings.HasPrefix(update.Message.Text, "/curie")
        if checkOne || checkTwo || checkThree {
            if checkOne {
                GptMode.MaxTokensGpt = 3000
                GptMode.NameBot = "text-davinci-003"
            } else if checkTwo {
                GptMode.MaxTokensGpt = 4096
                GptMode.NameBot = "code-davinci-002"
            } else {
                GptMode.MaxTokensGpt = 2048
                GptMode.NameBot = "text-curie-001"
            }
            update.Message.Text = "Вы выбрали режим " + GptMode.NameBot
        } else {
            update.Message.Text = sendChatGPT(chatGPT, update.Message.Text, GptMode)
        }

        // Send message to Telegram
        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, update.Message.Text)
        msg.ReplyToMessageID = update.Message.MessageID

        _, err = bot.Send(msg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error:", err)
        }
    }
}
```

При смене режима бота возвращает ошибку:

```
return "ChatGPT API error"
```

Comment: а вы напечатайте этот err перед ретёрном и посмотрите на ошибку. что пишет?

Comment: Cпасибо за подсказку.                                                                                                       
error, status code: 400, message: This model's maximum context length is 2049 tokens, however you requested 2055 tokens (7 in your prompt; 2048 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length.

Comment: расскажите своими словами, что говорит ошибка

Comment: По всей видимости идет превышение максимального количества токенов

Comment: Это сообщение означает, что вы использовали слишком длинный текст при запросе на генерацию текста

Comment: Уменьшил ограничение максимального количества токенов. Пока что без ошибок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error, status code: 400, message: This model's maximum context length is 2049 tokens, however you requested 2055 tokens (7 in your prompt; 2048 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length

Вы использовали слишком длинный текст при запросе на генерацию текста.
Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно уменьшить размер вашего запроса, удалив лишние слова или фразы из исходного запроса. Также можно использовать более короткие запросы или разбить более длинные запросы на несколько более коротких.

Answer (score 0):

Поменял код в return у функции **sendChatGPT**:

```
    resp, err := c.CreateCompletion(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }
```

Функция **CreateCompletion** возвратила ошибку такого вида:

> error, status code: 400, message: This model's maximum context length is 2049 tokens, however you requested 2055 tokens (7 in your prompt; 2048 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length.

Решил проблему уменьшения ограничения максимального количества токенов:

```
            if checkOne {
                GptMode.MaxTokensGpt = 3000
                GptMode.NameBot = "text-davinci-003"
            } else if checkTwo {
                GptMode.MaxTokensGpt = 3500
                GptMode.NameBot = "code-davinci-002"
            } else {
                GptMode.MaxTokensGpt = 1900
                GptMode.NameBot = "text-curie-001"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

В MaxTokensGpt необходимо передать значение которое будет <= чем длина контекста у данной модели, за минусом длины самого сообщения (вопроса) (для этого надо использовать библиотеку  [tiktoken](https://github.com/pkoukk/tiktoken-go))

Например, если размер контекста 4096, а ваш запрос (используя tiktoken) имеет длину 1000 токенов, то MaxTokensGpt должен быть равен 4096 - 1000 = 3096 (или меньше, если хотите ограничить длину ответа)